# Should I make a fuss about small typos I found in a reference book?

Tags: books, errors-erratum, distance-learning

I'm currently taking up a bachelor's degree in history at a distance-learning college. Since history is not a popular degree in that school, they don't revise their history books/ modules regularly. In fact, most of the modules they gave me were published about twenty years ago and contain few typos and outdated information. Should I make a fuss about this, or should I just correct the errors myself?

By the way, in general, the old references are still informative and useful.

Comment: What would your fuss accomplish?

Comment: Most institutions try to maintain accurate information especially in relation to their teaching. They will probably appreciate knowing about the inconsistencies in their information.

Answer (score 2):

Just send an email. Most authors keep an errata on their website.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. They need to be corrected. Otherwise, other students might learn wrong information. Overall, everyone should get updated and state-of-art information.